# Appium 1.6 , iOS 10: Swipe left on a specific element

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to swipe left on a particular element on **iOS 10 using Appium 1.6** to expose the delete button.

**Touch Action and Swipe** code for swiping left direction is working fine for appium 1.4 but the issue emerged only after we migrated to appium 1.6.

Any help is greatly Appreciated

Comment: Can you please share you code in case you could get this working ? I'm struggling since a day and not luck yet.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and now I found the solution.

Details:

```
 Appium 1.6.4 beta 
 Java-Client-5.x beta
```

> Appium 1.6.x - Swipe has been removed and we have to create own
>   TouchAction for swipe, in that waitAction() use negative value will
>   perform the fast swipe action. e.g waitAction(-200).

```
TouchAction action1 = new TouchAction(driver).press(x,y).waitAction(-200).moveTo(x_travel, y_travel).release();
        action1.perform();
```

Post your feedback.

Comment: I'm doing as below WebElement rowToSlide = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeApplication[1]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]//XCUIElementTypeTable[1]/XCUIElementTypeCell[1]"));
                                
                 TouchAction swipe = new TouchAction(driver).press(rowToSlide, 250 , 147)
                         .waitAction(-200).moveTo(rowToSlide, 200, 147).release();
          
                         swipe.perform();
          but instead of swipe, tap action is taking place on the element. I want to swipe a row a bit to left to unhide button below it. Please review

Comment: I tried your solution without passing element but it didn't work as well.

Comment: TouchAction swipe = new TouchAction(driver).press( 250 , 147) .waitAction(-200).moveTo( 200, 147).release(); swipe.perform();  Try this? and still issue exists change the moveTo(200,147)  to moveTo(150,147)

Comment: https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/580  , I think it's bug. do you know any open source project which similar element behavior, please share

Comment: No, I don't know  any open project which has left swipe. My current project, I was using  500 ms in waitAction in appium 1.5.3, upon upgrade to 1.6.3 the left swipe(kind of flick) was not working, then I have tried the solution by decreasing the waitAction value from 500 and it stars working on negative value with proper x,y and x-offset,y-offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void swipe(String direction, int offset, int time) {

        int y = appiumDriver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
        int x = appiumDriver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
        TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
        System.out.println(x+" "+y);
        System.out.println("Entering swipe");
        if("right".equalsIgnoreCase(direction))
        {
            System.out.println("Swipe Right");
            touchAction.press(x-offset, y/2).moveTo(-(x-(2*offset)), 0).release().perform();
        }else if("left".equalsIgnoreCase(direction)){
            System.out.println("Swipe Left");
            touchAction.press(offset, y/2).moveTo((x-(2*offset)), 0).release().perform();
        }else if("up".equalsIgnoreCase(direction)){
            System.out.println("Swipe Up");
            touchAction.press(x/2, offset).moveTo(0, y-(2*offset)).release().perform();
        }else if("down".equalsIgnoreCase(direction)){
            System.out.println("Swipe Down");
            touchAction.press(x/2, y-offset).moveTo(0, -(y-(2*offset))).release().perform();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Call flick_left and pass the WebElement.

**flick_left(element)**

```
public void flick_left(WebElement flick_element) {
        Point location = flick_element.getLocation();
        Dimension size = flick_element.getSize();

            int flick_x, flick_y, flick_start_x, flick_end_x,flick_start_y,flick_end_y;  

            flick_x =size.getWidth();       
            flick_y = location.y + (size.getHeight()/2);

            flick_start_x = flick_x - (int)((double)flick_x*0.25);
            flick_end_x = flick_x -(int)((double)flick_x*0.55);
            swipe(flick_start_x, flick_y, flick_end_x, flick_y,-200);

}



public void swipe(int swipe_start_x, int swipe_start_y, int swipe_end_x, int swipe_end_y,int duration){

        int x = swipe_start_x;
        int y = swipe_start_y;
        int x_travel =  swipe_end_x-swipe_start_x;
        int y_travel =  swipe_end_y-swipe_start_y;
        TouchAction action1 = new TouchAction(driver).press(x,y).waitAction(duration).moveTo(x_travel, y_travel).release();
        action1.perform();


    }
```

Comment: Please mention which version of appium server and client has this new method ? https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7815 , please review this as well. It seems since last few weeks many are having issue with swipe action.

Comment: This is custom function I have created for the project with TouchAction. Appium 1.6.4 beta and java-client 5.0.0-BETA2

Comment: Could you try and let me know ,does it work for you?

Comment: I tried similar approach and come to conclusion that there is bug on appium server side. please refer to https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7914. I was surprised if swipe method got added back. Refer to issue 7815 for that reference

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: https://github.com/appium/java-client . Swipe is deprecated,  check this "The list of classes and methods which were marked deprecated and they are going to be removed" . Just for Ref.